# Apache Felix OSGi framework's WeavingHook.weave() method isn't invoked

Tags: java, osgi, apache-felix, load-time-weaving

I use [fabric8-karaf-1.1.0.CR5](http://fabric8.io/gitbook/getStarted.html) which includes:

```
.../system/org/apache/felix/org.apache.felix.framework/4.0.3.redhat-610379/org.apache.felix.framework-4.0.3.redhat-610379.jar
```

[.../org.apache.felix.framework-4.0.0/doc/changelog.txt](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/felix/releases/org.apache.felix.framework-4.0.0/doc/changelog.txt) contains:

```
 ** New Feature
     * [FELIX-2959] - [Framework] Implement OSGi R4.3 class loader byte-code weaving hook
```

I added to `.../etc/startup.properties`:

```
igb/igb.osgi.weaving/1.0.0/igb.osgi.weaving-1.0.0.jar=1
```

My bundle's activator:

```
package igb.osgi.weaving;

import java.util.Hashtable;

import org.osgi.framework.BundleActivator;
import org.osgi.framework.BundleContext;
import org.osgi.framework.hooks.weaving.WeavingHook;

public class Activator implements BundleActivator   {
    public void start( BundleContext bc ) throws Exception {
        System.out.println( "Starting " + Activator.class.getName() );
        // this doesn't work
        //bc.registerService( Weaver.class, new Weaver(), new Hashtable<String, Object>() );
        // this is the proper way, see BJ Hargrave's accepted answer below
        bc.registerService( WeavingHook.class, new Weaver(), new Hashtable<String, Object>() );
        }
    public void stop( BundleContext bc ) throws Exception {
        System.out.println( "Stopping " + Activator.class.getName() );
        }
    } // Activator
```

My WeavingHook:

```
package igb.osgi.weaving;

import org.osgi.framework.hooks.weaving.WeavingHook;
import org.osgi.framework.hooks.weaving.WovenClass;

public class Weaver implements WeavingHook {
    synchronized public void weave( WovenClass wc ) {
        System.out.println( "Weaving " + wc.getClassName() );
        }
} // Weaver
```

`.../system/igb/igb.osgi.weaving/1.0.0/igb.osgi.weaving-1.0.0.jar/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF`:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bnd-LastModified: 1406380868073
Build-Jdk: 1.7.0_51
Built-By: Geri
Bundle-Activator: igb.osgi.weaving.Activator
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: IGB OSGi Weaving
Bundle-SymbolicName: igb.osgi.weaving
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0
Created-By: Apache Maven Bundle Plugin
Export-Package: igb.osgi.weaving;uses:="org.osgi.framework,org.osgi.fram
 ework.hooks.weaving";version="1.0.0"
Import-Package: org.osgi.framework;version="[1.7,2)",org.osgi.framework.
 hooks.weaving;version="[1.0,2)"
Require-Capability: osgi.ee;filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.7))"
Tool: Bnd-2.3.0.201405100607
```

My bundle is started at Fabric8's start:

```
Please wait while Fabric8 is loading...
Starting igb.osgi.weaving.Activator
100% [========================================================================]

______    _          _      _____
|  ___|  | |        (_)    |  _  |
| |_ __ _| |__  _ __ _  ___ \ V /
|  _/ _` | '_ \| '__| |/ __|/ _ \
| || (_| | |_) | |  | | (__| |_| |
\_| \__,_|_.__/|_|  |_|\___\_____/
  Fabric8 Container (1.1.0.CR5)
  http://fabric8.io/

Type 'help' to get started
and 'help [cmd]' for help on a specific command.
Hit '<ctrl-d>' or 'osgi:shutdown' to shutdown this container.

Open a browser to http://localhost:8181 to access the management console

Create a new Fabric via 'fabric:create'
or join an existing Fabric via 'fabric:join [someUrls]'

Fabric8:karaf@root>
```

But there's no "Weaving ..." output from my Weaver object.

My bundle is active:

```
Fabric8:karaf@root>  list|grep IGB
[   1] [Active     ] [            ] [    1] IGB OSGi Weaving (1.0.0)
```

My Weaver service is recognized:

```
Fabric8:karaf@root> ls 1
You are about to access system bundle 1.  Do you wish to continue (yes/no): yes

IGB OSGi Weaving (1) provides:
------------------------------
objectClass = igb.osgi.weaving.Weaver
service.id = 3
```

But it seems that it is not used:

```
Fabric8:karaf@root> ls -u|grep -i igb
Fabric8:karaf@root>
```

Lines of `.../data/log/karaf.log` containing `igb`:

```
Line 27: 2014-07-26 14:38:28,426 | DEBUG | -610379-thread-1 | BlueprintExtender                | 10 - org.apache.aries.blueprint.core - 1.0.1.redhat-610379 | Scanning bundle igb.osgi.weaving for blueprint application
Line 28: 2014-07-26 14:38:28,426 | DEBUG | -610379-thread-1 | BlueprintExtender                | 10 - org.apache.aries.blueprint.core - 1.0.1.redhat-610379 | No blueprint application found in bundle igb.osgi.weaving
Line 6824: 2014-07-26 14:38:33,028 | DEBUG | y-1.1.0-thread-1 | geronimo-osgi-registry           | 113 - org.apache.geronimo.specs.geronimo-osgi-registry - 1.1.0 | Bundle Considered for class providers: igb.osgi.weaving
Line 6825: 2014-07-26 14:38:33,028 | DEBUG | y-1.1.0-thread-1 | geronimo-osgi-registry           | 113 - org.apache.geronimo.specs.geronimo-osgi-registry - 1.1.0 | adding bundle igb.osgi.weaving [1]
Line 12143: 2014-07-26 14:38:39,783 | INFO  | .Beta37-thread-1 | runtime                          | 59 - gravia-runtime-api - 1.1.0.Beta37 | Installed: Module[igb.osgi.weaving:1.0.0]
Line 12343: 2014-07-26 14:38:40,017 | DEBUG | .Beta37-thread-1 | resource                         | 58 - gravia-resource - 1.1.0.Beta37 | Add to RuntimeEnvironment: Resource[igb.osgi.weaving:1.0.0]
Line 12344: 2014-07-26 14:38:40,017 | DEBUG | .Beta37-thread-1 | resource                         | 58 - gravia-resource - 1.1.0.Beta37 |    IdentityCapability[atts={gravia.identity=igb.osgi.weaving, version=1.0.0},[igb.osgi.weaving:1.0.0]]
Line 12344: 2014-07-26 14:38:40,017 | DEBUG | .Beta37-thread-1 | resource                         | 58 - gravia-resource - 1.1.0.Beta37 |    IdentityCapability[atts={gravia.identity=igb.osgi.weaving, version=1.0.0},[igb.osgi.weaving:1.0.0]]
Line 13469: 2014-07-26 14:38:43,168 | DEBUG | -2.13.2-thread-1 | Activator                        | 155 - org.apache.camel.camel-core - 2.13.2 | Bundle started: igb.osgi.weaving
```

The [OSGi Service Platform Release 4 Version 4.3 Core Specification, 56.3 The Weaving Service, page 351](http://www.osgi.org/Download/Release4V43) reads:

> The framework picks up the Weaving Hook services and calls their weave method for each class that must be loaded.

I interpret this as having nothing else to do. Where am I wrong?

PS: `Activator`'s code adapted to reflect the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to register the service under the OSGi Weaving Hook Service name so the framework can find it.

```
bc.registerService( org.osgi.framework.hooks.weaving.WeavingHook.class, new Weaver(), new Hashtable<String, Object>() );
```

The framework has no idea what your igb.osgi.weaving.Weaver service is.

Comment: That's it! Thank you!

Though the framework could know since the Weaver,class is derived from org.osgi.framework.hooks.weaving.WeavingHook, so a simple `instancof` could reveal it.

Furthermore, (BundleContext's javadoc)(http://www.osgi.org/javadoc/r4v43/core/org/osgi/framework/BundleContext.html#registerService%28java.lang.Class,%20S,%20java.util.Dictionary%29) mislead me since it calls the parameter `clazz`

Comment: (*grrr* "Comments may only be edited for 5 minutes")


... `clazz - The class under whose name the service can be located.`

WeavingHook is an interface. Is the specification not precise or is the implementation not precisely according to the specification, but according to general sense?

Comment: After thinking a bit I came to the conclusion that `ìnstanceof` for _all_ of the services at registering of _each_ service (cartesian product) would bloat the framework's code unnecessarily and probably raise performance issues, too. So, the framework as it is does a goood job, as always. Though there could be examples which make this clear. But now there is at least one above... :-)